# how to get request getattribute value in jsp use jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have one servlet page and one jsp page.

Jsp:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.href + "?b=b",
                success:function(data){
                    //doSomething(data); 
                    console.info('${testtemp}');  // it’s not work fine
                }
            });
```

Servlet:

```
    String testtemp = DateUtil.fmtTimestamp(
            new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), "/", ":", " ",
            esunbank.esunutil.DateUtil.DateFmt_Mode_Datetime);

    request.setAttribute("testtemp", testtemp);
```

I want to use jquery ajax method to get the parameter from servlet and update in jsp. Now the only way I can get the current answer is get data from ‘data’.

```
success: function(data){
    //doSomething(data); 
}
```

And then retrieve ‘data’ (doSomething), but I am not sure is there a better way to do that.

Thank you everyone for helping me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it just a string you're returning, you can write to your output stream:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain"); 
response.getWriter().write(testtemp);
```

JS:

```
success: function(data){
 console.log(data); // your time
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes it can work, but for me the servlet is a controller in spring mvc. If I don’t want to modify any code in servlet (java). Is there any other suggestion?